Not able to login to a user through another user in Vagrant
I have a main user scriptbox where all three other web01, web02, web03 are connected.
Web03 is an ubuntu based VM and other two are centos. They are running fine but web03 is not doing, it keep showing the same error.
 ssh vagrant@web03
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:bDhBR1PkTV5ul8t9aW/g7VrUfFs9Tps9XrzdchbLMto.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
ECDSA host key for web03 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.


What are the chances that you rebuilt web03 after you first connected to it? =)

Maybe the following is a hint? Offending ECDSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3 ECDSA host key for web03 has changed and you have requested strict checking. Delete line 3 your in /root/.ssh/known_hosts file and try again?

@htor - I tried to see that but it seems the file doesnt exist in that /root/ssh/ only a file called authorized keys are there and it is also not shoiwng anything
